# Conditionals in Helm template

Tags: json, go, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to define a helm template with an `if` conditional, but I'm not being able to achieve it. The JSON template are inside the files directory inside my helm-chart and it is like that:

```
{
  "default_project": "{{ .Values.ss_api_ob }}",
       "roaming": {
          "xxx": "false",
          "xxx": "xxx.json",
          "xxx": "xx.json",
          "xxx": "xxx.json",
          "xxx": "correspondences.json",
         if  "{{- eq .Values.myvar "es" -}}"
          "xxxx": {{ '[["xxx", "xxx"], ["xxx", "xx"], ["xx", "xxxx"], ["xx", "xx"]]' }},
          {{- else -}}
         "xxx": {{ '[["yyy", "yyy"], ["yyy", "yyy"], ["yyy", "yyy"]]' }},
         {{- end -}}
          "xxxx": "http://{{ .Values.kongService }}:9800/xxxx",
          "xxx": "http://{{ .Values.kongService }}:9800/xxxxx",
          "xxxx": "http://{{ .Values.kongService }}:9800/xxxx"
        },
}
```

`myvar = es` so the json file should define the first choice. But when I try to install it I'm getting an error like something is wrong:

```
Error: template: api/templates/configmap.yaml:7:7: executing "api/templates/configmap.yaml" at <tpl (.Files.Glob "files/*").AsConfig .>:  parse error at (api/templates/configmap.yaml:5): unclosed action
```

I have checked my JSON template but I don't find where is the problem. Any idea?

Comment: What's this? `{{ '[["xxx", "xxx"], ["xxx", "xx"], ["xx", "xxxx"], ["xx", "xx"]]' }}` Apostrophe is used to create a character (rune) constant, and not a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `if` is outside the action.
2. The action is unnecessarily quoted.

The following ought to work:

```json
{
  "default_project": "{{ .Values.ss_api_ob }}",
       "roaming": {
          "xxx": "false",
          "xxx": "xxx.json",
          "xxx": "xx.json",
          "xxx": "xxx.json",
          "xxx": "correspondences.json",
          {{- if eq .Values.myvar "es" -}}
          "xxxx": {{ `[["xxx", "xxx"], ["xxx", "xx"], ["xx", "xxxx"], ["xx", "xx"]]` }},
          {{- else -}}
          "xxx": [["yyy", "yyy"], ["yyy", "yyy"], ["yyy", "yyy"]],
          {{- end -}}
          "xxxx": "http://{{ .Values.kongService }}:9800/xxxx",
          "xxx": "http://{{ .Values.kongService }}:9800/xxxxx",
          "xxxx": "http://{{ .Values.kongService }}:9800/xxxx"
        },
}
```

Comment: @mkpriva Sorry, using your way I'm getting same error.. :(

Comment: @hachecheche checkout icza's comment, he's right, either use `\`` for a string inside an action, or just remove the action delimiters, they seem to be pointless there.

Comment: @hachecheche i've updated the code in the answer to show both options, in the if block the `\`` is used, in the else block the `{{` and `}}` are removed. If you're still getting an error, the same or a different one, then the problem is caused by something else, something that you haven't included in the question.